# How to get urls from apk file?

Tags: android, apk

I would like to get the URLs from which the apps loaded data, for example, the cities shown below.

[image]

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eK-cc2cwXFHqII_hcotnbCFgmUcd3AFP) is the apk file.

I opened it with Android Studio.

The folder structure is shown [image: here].

I searched and found lots of XML files but cannot find any URLs.

Where should I get the URLs from which the apps get data?

Thank you very much.

Comment: you should decode the app then you find URL from the decoded code.
decode from : 
http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

Comment: Make sure you are allowed to reverse-engineer the application you are trying to get URLs from. Most publushers don't allow it.

Comment: @Hardik, Thank you. I have decoded the code. However, there are still many files...

Comment: @Chan , if you find API url  , may be its available in java file.

Comment: I searched all java files but no urls. Can you please help?